# Android Library Dependencies broken after SDK/ADT-Update

Tags: android, eclipse, dependencies, android-library, buildpath

Today, I updated my Android SDK and Eciple ADT to the most recent versions (ADT Rev 22). After restarting Eclipse it is quite unhappy with the Build Paths whenever I reference custom libraries.

An example is shown in this screenshot:
[image]

My custom "Android Utilities Library" compiles fine, but everything that depends on it shows build path errors. E.g. when I investigate the build path settings for "Android URA Library" it shows me an error with the `android_utilities_library.jar` missing under "Android Dependencies" (which in fact is true, the libraries will be built to individual class files in `bin/classes`).

After reading the solution to [Build path errors with library projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110534/build-path-errors-with-library-projects) I tried to clean and manually build my projects in the correct order, but to no avail.

I've never dealt with this before, so I don't know how to attack the problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thx!

Comment: try this: go to the order and export tab and tick the box beside your custom libs, then try clean and build.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update/16610247#16610247) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update/16608570#16608570). Those are two solutions to the most common problems in ADT 22.

Comment: Installing the new Build Tools did the trick. Thx!

Comment: please move it to answered

Comment: wow been 10 hours desperately trying different things. Thanks for this post guys! I was close to switch to iphone xDD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing the new Build Tools did the trick. They were not automatically included when I updated the SDK (probably need to run the update twice I guess).

Comment: yep you are right.. the first time I updated and deleted packages and I thought that everything is OK !! but the same error above appeared so when I run the update again (Window - Android SDK Manager) I had new packages to delete and install others .. So after the second update I could work well. Thanks for your answer chris :))

Comment: Hi, i have same issue. i did like you said. installed new build tools buy still there is problem. android dependancy has red cross over it and i can not run my any project. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that works for me:
Go to Project Properties > Build Path > Order and Export

Then you have to check each checkbox.
In my case my libraries were restored

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that your project `Android URA Library` is referring to `Android Utilities Library`, then the problem should not relate to SDK/ADT update.

Please check:

1. Project Properties of `Android URA Library`, choose Project tab and make sure you added `Android Utilities Library` as dependency project. Otherwise, please add it.
2. If the problem is still existing, then Projects \ Clean All Projects

Answer (score 0):

Go to libraries and check the build path of the dependent libraries. It should be same as your projects build path.

Answer (score -1):

if you have import all the Dependencies in your workSpace.maybe you can:projetc-->build all.
I meet the problem,and it works well